# Find the correct math words to equals the intended number

Tags: mathematics, word, formation-of-numbers

I am testing a new puzzle.
I hope the puzzles are intersting.

**Example:**

- 3 7 7 2 4 = 40
  **Answer:** two(3) hundred(7) divided(7) by(2) five(4) = 40

**Rules:**

- Find the correct words.
- Numbers of letters have been determined in the questions.
- The only operators can be used are :
  "plus", "add", "added to", "minus", "subtracted from", "times", "multiplied by", "divided by", "squared", "cubed", "square root of", "cube root of", "sinus", "sin", "cosinus", "cos", "tangent", "tan", "degree", "log".

**Questions:**

- 5 4 5 5 4 5 = 200
- 6 4 2 5 4 5 5 = 5
- 5 6 6 4 4 = 5
- 4 4 2 5 4 5 = 10
- 5 5 4 5 5 4 = 100

**Note :**

- If there are problems in the rules, we can work together to edit the rules.

Comment: This seems like a LOT of trial and error, especially with sinus cosinus and their abbreviations. Also if I understood the rules correctly, five(5) and by(3) are wrong because theses are 4 and 2 letters respectively..

Comment: @stackreader  Sorry for the error in example, I hope (think) no more error.

Comment: I have checked the questions 3 times, I am sure no more error there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partial answer:

By simple inspection of strange word lengths, we notice presence of the word "Of". In context of the fact that we may use trig functions, we can infer that "degree" will probably appear, and work out the trig function from there. "Square Root Of" and "Cube Root Of" were fairly easy to identify. Beyond that, the first and last exercises seem extremely laborsome and aimless unless a program is written.

6 4 2 5 4 5 5 = 5

> Square Root Of Sixty Four Minus Three = $\sqrt{64} - 3 = 5$

5 6 6 4 4 = 5

> Sinus Ninety Degree Plus Four = $\sin{90}^\circ + 4 = 5$

4 4 2 5 4 5 = 10

> Cube Root Of Eight Plus Eight = $\sqrt[3]{8} + 8 = 10$

Comment: All three are right!, still waiting for another two. I still think no need to write a program.

Answer (score 6):

For the last one, I got

5 5 4 5 5 4 = 100

> sixty eight plus eight times four = $68 + 8 \cdot 4 = 100$

Of course there might be other solutions.

Comment: stack reader answered 5 4 5 5 4 5 = 200 first.

Comment: Yup, sorry, we were editing at the same time. Is the proper etiquette to edit it out of my answer or leave it there?

Comment: Right !. All 4 are the same with mine except 5 5 4 5 5 4 = 100. I have another answer for 5 5 4 5 5 4 = 100.

Comment: I think, better to edit it out. Let it be stack reader's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a partial answer

> sixty(5) four(4) times(5) three(5) plus(4) eight(5) = 200